# Call APIs methods in a way which is safe against changes between library versions in JAVA

Tags: java, reflection

I have to call a java method in a third party JAR, in a way which is compatible with two different versions of the API.

The difference is minimal as there's one additional parameter in the new version, but I should ensure that my app works and compiles with both versions of the library.

The best option I've come with is using reflection to check which version of the various methods is available, and then call the correct one at run-time, but was wandering if there's a more elegant way, maybe using some third party library.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you *know* which version of the third party library your code will be linking against beforehand, you can have a small wrapper library separately to provide a common interface to both API versions.

If you do not have that ability reflection is probably the way to go. Depending on how your project and its build system are setup, you might even be able to use a couple of adapter classes that will be loaded at runtime after the API version of the third party library is detected. This way you would not suffer the performance impact associated with reflective method calls.

That said, you might want to look at dealing with such dependency issues using a proper deployment framework, such as [OSGi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi).

Comment: @RaffaeleCastagno: yes, but do you control which version is shipped with each copy of your application?

Comment: I currently have exactly two versions of the libraries.

Introducing dependencies management with maven or similar is not an option, would take too much time (the entire app is pretty big). 

My problem is that the library provider introduced some changes in the latest patch, and we currently have two different versions installed on our customers systems, and we must assure that our common codebase in compatible with both.

I'll try with a wrapper, before going for the reflection approach. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry @thkala I've rewritten my comment before seeing yours. 

Answer is yes, sort of: involved library is part of a customized application container, so I know exactly which version I'm going to use, and as a very last resort I should be able to do some parametric stuff at build-time. Anyway, as I written, I just had some idea about how I could implement a wrapper for the changing libraries. Will test tomorrow.